# Phonegap Windows 7 application hangs on document.addEventListener with backbutton

Tags: windows, cordova, addeventlistener

I am trying my first Phonegap application for Windows Phone 7.

I have installed Windows Mobile SDK 7.1 (including emulator, VS2010 for Win Phone, XNA, e.t.c.) on a Windows 7 Pro workstation as well as Phonegap 3.4.0 (which contains the wp7 platform) via NodeJS.

I have created my first project with phonegap command from the command line (phonegap create ...). 
I have added the wp7 platform also with the phonegap command (phonegap build wp7).
I have opened the created project in VS2010 for Win Phone in order to run it on the emulator.
... everything runs ok so far = the app starts on the emulator ... (remember it is the **Phonegap default sample application**)

However if I add the following code in the handling function riggered on deviceready event it seems to hang:

```
...
console.log('call document.addEventListener("backbutton")');
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton,false);
console.log('end document.addEventListener ok');
...
```

The first log output is executed but the second log output does not appear. It seems it **hangs on addEventListener("backbutton",...)** ... If I comment this line out I get both log outputs.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // `load`, `deviceready`, `offline`, and `online`.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    // The scope of `this` is the event. In order to call the `receivedEvent`
    // function, we must explicity call `app.receivedEvent(...);`
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        console.log('call document.addEventListener("backbutton")');
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackButton,false);
        console.log('end document.addEventListener ok');
    },

    onBackButton: function() { }
};
```

Output:

```
Received Event: deviceready
call document.addEventListener("backbutton")
```

According to Phonegap documentation the "backbutton" event is supported on Windows 7: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

**UPDATE:**

I have found out that I need to use the context 'this', so I have corrected to:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackButton ,false);
```

... however it did not work either. On the other hand if I try to register a different event, f.x. 'click' it works fine, i.e. the execution goes further as it should (I get the second log output) and I get the event when I click on the document.

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.onBackButton ,false);
```

Does anybody have an idea, suggestion or solution?

**UPDATE 2:**

Adding some more debug output via a function like:

```
window.onerror = function(message, file, line)
{
  console.log('error on ' + file + ' at ' + line + ': ' + message);
}
```

I get the following extra error:

```
error on x-wmapp1:/app/www/cordova.js at 827: 'ArrayBuffer' is undefined
```

I have no idea what is the connection between addEventListener('backbutton') and ArrayBuffer but it looks like a bug in cordova !? ... or ... that ArrayBuffer is not defined in Windows Phone SDK 7.1 !?

Have anybody meet this before?

Thank you
Radu

Comment: As i can see that the `onBackbutton` is a method of the `app` object. you need to add the callback with the **app** context `document.addEventListener("backbutton", app.onBackButton,false);`. Also you need to put in some statements in the `onBackButton` function. `onBackButton: function() { console.log("onBackButton Called"); }`. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I have tried with both app.onBackButton and this.onBackButton but it did not help, it does not pass the addEventListener line. I even tried like document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){ console.log('onBackButton call'); } ,false); in order to eliminate some failure-points but it still does not work. However if I try to register a different event document.addEventListener("online"...), it goes further as it should.

Comment: Can you try the same code on the WP8 emulator?. Also you could try the App in an actual WP7 device, if you have one. It could be that the WP7 emulator is buggy. What I can tell is that I have used cordova 3.4 with android kitkat (4.4.2) and the `backbutton` functionality does work.

Comment: I know it works fine in Android ... actually my whole plan was to deploy on Win Phone an application I made initially for Android but it gets hanging at this point. Testing on Win8 and WP8 emu is out of reach for me at the moment... however thanks a lot for input